# How can I fix Requested JSON parse failed issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, api

I want to send the information I get in the form to the api. And I'm doing this with ajax.

My codes are like this.

```
var data = [{
    "name": "Deborah",
    "surname": "Herzog",
    "day": "1",
    "month": "7"
}, {
    "name": "Hunter",
    "surname": "Strachan",
    "day": "7",
    "month": "10"
}]

$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: "https://someapi.com/1",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    success: function(result) {
        console.log("success");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, exception) {
        getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception);
    }
});

function getErrorMessage(jqXHR, exception) {
    var msg = '';
    if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
        msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
        msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
    } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
        msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
    } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
        msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
    } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
        msg = 'Time out error.';
    } else if (exception === 'abort') {
        msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
    } else {
        msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
    }
    console.log(msg);
};
```

When I first make my datype as json, it says "has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status." gave an error.

After some research, I changed the dataType to "jsonp" and this problem went away.

But this time "Requested JSON parse failed." I started getting the error.
Even though I changed the data format, I couldn't solve this problem. (Like stringing the data).

How do you think I can solve this problem?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Accept: application/json` when using JSONP. JSONP is not JSON, it's JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure the API implements JSONP? It's not automatic.

Comment: Look at the source of your page, find the `<script>` tag created by the JSONP request and see what's wrong with it.